# Terminologie : « linear and angular momentum » vs « quantité de mouvement et moment cinétique »

Tags: anglais, comparaison-de-langues, physique

En anglais on utilise :

> linear momentum and angular momentum

en français, respectivement,

> quantité de mouvement et moment cinétique

Pourquoi existe-t-il cette différence dans la terminologie entre les deux langues ?

En revanche,  on utilise

> moment of inertia et moment d'inertie

respectivement.

Comment: Bien qu'étant un anglicisme, on utilise couramment « Moment angulaire » en français.

Comment: Le fait que anglais et français soient à peu près d'accord sur « moment d'inertie » / « moment of inertia » (bien qu'il y ait des variantes) rend tout ça encore plus énigmatique.

Comment: En fait c'est plus une question de (ou d'histoire de la) physique que de français ou d'anglais. Ce serait peut être mieux de poser cette question sur [physics.se] si elle n'existe pas déjà.

Comment: Absolument d'accord avec le commentaire de SG ci-dessus. De fait, comme on utilise aussi en français les termes de *moment linéaire* et de *moment angulaire* cela signifie que... cela n'est pas tout à fait la même chose que, respectivement, *la quantité de mouvement* et *le moment cinétique*. Tu auras juste loupé un drond quelque part et ça... c'est sur Physics qu'on te l'expliquera... ;)

Comment: J'aimerais ajouter qu'en français, le moment est le produit d'une force par une distance (et encore multiplié par le sinus de l'angle entre le vecteur force et le vecteur déplacement). Les anglophones utilisent non pas "momentum" pour exprimer le "moment d'une force" mais "torque" pour l'équivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour "angular momentum", on peut utiliser soit : "moment cinetique" ou "moment angulaire"

Pour "linear momentum", on peut utiliser soit : "vitesse linéaire" ou "quantité de mouvement"

---

Pour avoir une réponse exacte, il faut poser la question respectivement à l'Académie française (qui à tendance à lutter activement contre les anglicismes) et aussi à son équivalent anglais.

L'usage de la langue de Shakespeare étant un standard dans les revues scientifiques, je pense que la France a désiré se différencier.

Comment: Alors qu'on envoie un courriel à l'Ac. et au soit-disant équivalent du côté anglo-saxon et qu'on transcrive leur réponse pour répondre.

Comment: @Survenant9r7, je t'invite à le faire :-)

Answer (score 1):

D'après un [article de recherche](https://journals.openedition.org/trivium/4638) sur le sens du mot "moment", il est à noter qu'en anglais il existe également deux mots de sens distincts:

- The momentum, qui traduit la tendance d'un objet à continuer sur sa lancée. En termes physiques, cela se traduit par la *quantité de mouvement*, mais dans le domaine général cela se traduirait par l'*élan* (*build up momentum = donner de l'élan*)
- The moment, en français le *moment*, qui est le produit vectoriel d'un vecteur avec le vecteur position du point d'application de ce vecteur. Le moment d'une force par rapport à un axe traduit la tendance de la force à faire tourner un objet autour de cet axe. Le moment de la quantité de mouvement, c'est le moment cinétique.

Ces deux mots partagent une même origine latine qui peut prêter à confusion et à ré-emprunts, comme par exemple *angular momentum* / *moment cinétique* traduit parfois en *moment angulaire*, qui correspondrait à la fois en anglais à un *moment* (puisqu'il est un produit vectoriel) et un *momentum* (il représente la poursuite continue d'une rotation autour d'un axe) — d'ailleurs, une forme aujourd'hui peu usitée de *angular momentum* en anglais est *moment of momentum*.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 merci, lien mis à jour